# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when printing tiff file using Java Print Service

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm using Java Print Service to print a tiff file, it causes "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

```
      private void sendToPrinter(String fileToPrint) throws PrintException, IOException
      {
          /* Use the pre-defined flavor for a GIF from an InputStream */
          DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;

          /* Create a set which specifies how the job is to be printed */
          PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
          aset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
          aset.add(new Copies(1));

          /* Create a Print Service using the default printer */
          PrintService ps=PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
          DocPrintJob job=ps.createPrintJob();

//          System.gc();
          try (FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fileToPrint))
          {
              Doc doc=new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null); 
              job.print(doc, aset);
          }
      }
```

Stack trace:

```
2020-04-23 15:32:03|DEBUG|SHPSKD010_160_TEST|Printing \\kanesrv02\imagedocs\certs\61107282.tif
2020-04-23 15:32:20|ERROR|SHPSKD010_160_TEST|java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.loops.GraphicsPrimitive.convertFrom(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.loops.GraphicsPrimitive.convertFrom(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.loops.MaskBlit$General.MaskBlit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.loops.Blit$GeneralMaskBlit.Blit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.renderImageXform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.transformImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.scaleImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.copyImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.copyImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WPathGraphics.drawImageToPlatform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.PathGraphics.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.PathGraphics.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.ImagePrinter.print(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.printableJob(Unknown Source)
    at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.kanebridge.op.ui.SHPSKD010_160_TEST.sendToPrinter(Unknown Source)
    at com.kanebridge.op.ui.SHPSKD010_160_TEST.PRTALL_actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.kanebridge.common.ui.BasePanel.callMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.kanebridge.common.ui.BasePanel.callMethod(Unknown Source)
```

The tif file is pretty small, a little over 500K, containing 7 pages.
Googled quite a bit, but couldn't find much help. Saw a post suggesting calling the Garbage Collection explicitly before printing. Tried, but did not work.
JVM heap size already set to max of 512mb.

`java-vm-args="-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"`

The goal of the program is to print a copy of the certificate automatically (without the user interaction) to user's default printer after finishing processing a shipment.

Why would it cause the memory issue since the file is not that large, and how to resolve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the below steps.

1. Start your application from command prompt using the below command

   java -jar -Xmx1024M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps “\your.jar” >> C:\Temp\Log.txt
2. Open a new command prompt and navigate to JDK Bin directory and type

   jcmd
3. Now note down the process ID for your process and type

   jmap -heap

   4. Now you will know how much memory is assigned to young, old and heap and how much percentage is used.

This will help you figure out what is happening with your application. Please try and let us know if it helped.

Comment: This's a webstart app though, not sure if it's possible to test as suggested, I'll need to find a way to do so, and update once tried. Thank you!

Comment: Now I thought about it more, is it a possible restriction in a webstart app/applet? Because when I tried it in Eclipse dev env, I didn't get the OOM error.